# Dockerfile build incorrect behavior

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have a Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.2-fpm-alpine

# Install packages
RUN apk add --no-cache curl git build-base zlib-dev oniguruma-dev autoconf bash
RUN apk add --update linux-headers

# Xdebug
ARG INSTALL_XDEBUG=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_XDEBUG} = true ]; \
    then \
      pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug; \
    fi;

COPY ./docker/php-fpm/xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini



# Configure non-root user.
ARG PUID=1000
ARG PGID=1000
RUN apk --no-cache add shadow && \
    groupmod -o -g ${PGID} www-data && \
    usermod -o -u ${PUID} -g www-data www-data

# Nginx
RUN apk add --update --no-cache nginx
COPY ./docker/php-fpm/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
RUN chown -Rf www-data:www-data /var/lib/nginx

# Supervisor
RUN apk add --no-cache supervisor
COPY ./docker/php-fpm/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf

# Source code
RUN chown www-data:www-data /var/www
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data ./ /var/www
WORKDIR /var/www

# Postgres
RUN apk add --no-cache libpq-dev && docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsq

# Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
ARG BUILD_MODE=dev
RUN if [ ${BUILD_MODE} = dev ]; \
    then \
      composer install --no-interaction; \
    else \
      composer install --no-dev --no-interaction --no-progress --no-scripts --optimize-autoloader; \
    fi;
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/vendor/

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["/bin/sh", "./docker/php-fpm/run.sh"]
```

When the process of installing pdo_pgsq, everything stop as below, timer is working, but nothing happening.  and the same problem with composer install after.

```
[php-fpm stage-0 15/18] RUN apk add --no-cache libpq-dev && docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql pdo                                                                454.2s
 => => # more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
 => => # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 => => # Build complete.
 => => # Don't forget to run 'make test'.
 => => # + strip --strip-all modules/pdo_pgsql.so
 => => # Installing shared extensions:     /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/
```

Macos Sonoma 14.4

Docker version 25.0.3, build 4debf41

Docker Compose version v2.24.6-desktop.1

PHP 8.2.17 (cli) (built: Mar 12 2024 14:26:30) (NTS)

Comment: Just to be sure, in your Dockerfile you have declared the package as `pdo_pgsql` and no `pdo_pgsq` ?